# how to set scrollbar image using css?

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, flexbox

I am trying to make `custom scrollbar` I found a image of `scrollbar` which is working fine when background is `white`.But when the background is `back` my scrollbar is not display (as both have same color) .Can we get `white` background image for scrollbar . from where I will get `white scrollbar image` in base 64 formate.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/nivepoyoye/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="abc pqr" style="background:#000">
    asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
    sdasd
  </div>
```

my scrollbar is not display

```
.pqr::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAALCAIAAADa28u7AAAABnRSTlMAAAAAAABupgeRAAAAEklEQVR4AWPAB8REhYEIjcIDADhRAXVLIXYqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-position:0 50%;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
/*     background-color:#fff
     */ }

    .pqr::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 18px;
    }
```

From where I will get `white` scrollbar in base64 ? so that it look great

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: red green;
}

/* Works on Chrome/Edge/Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
```